# Exclusive access to variable in mapLimit return

Tags: node.js, async.js

I'm reasonably new to programming in nodejs but not to programming (C/C++/Python/Shaders) and I have a question about exclusive access to a global variable when e.g. async.mapLimit return its callbacks

example

```
var myGlobalCounter = 0;

function executeDownload(item, callback){

  exec('./ascriptthatdownload.sh ' + item, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    // Here do I have exclusive access to myGlobalCounter
    // so that I could do this or update lets say a UI component?
    myGlobalCounter++
    console.log('Downloads ready:', myGlobalCounter);
  });   
}

function downloadSomeFiles() {
  var listOfFiles = [];
  // create download links
  async.mapLimit(listOfFiles, 4, executeDownload, function(err, results){

  });
}
```

I can get this to work but I don't know if this is safe enough? Other suggestions also appreciated. In C/C++ I would have used a mutex to guard against simultaneous access to myGlobalCounter.

Edit:I want to be able to safely count myGlobalCounter by 1 each time a download is ready and then pass it on either in console.log or to another component

Comment: What do you mean, "safe enough"? What do you want to guard against exactly?

Comment: I want to be able to safely count myGlobalCounter by 1 each time a download is ready and then pass it on either in console.log or to another component

Comment: Sure, `myGlobalCounter++` will indeed increment `myGlobalCounter` as desired..? Whenever you reference `myGlobalCounter`, you will get its current value

Comment: @CertainPerformance and I can be sure that only one callback at a time accesses myGlobalCounter?

Comment: Yes, Javascript is single-threaded - a synchronous block of code will run to the end before any other callback can run, look up the event loop. You almost never have to worry about shared mutable state in JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kudos goes to @CertainPerformance explanation in his comment (that I can't accept as an answer)

> Yes, Javascript is single-threaded - a synchronous block of code will
>   run to the end before any other callback can run, look up the event
>   loop. You almost never have to worry about shared mutable state in JS